# Duplicating content blocks

Tags: 8, entities, blocks

Is there a way to clone or make copies of blocks?

For example, we have some blocks that are quite bespoke. We need to make multiple copies of them so we can display certain content within them on different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [entity_clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_clone) module, which allows you to clone entities.

You can also clone blocks

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's worked. I made an error initially but got it to work after realising my mistake.